# Raspbian restart network without reboot

Tags: networking, usb, raspberry-pi, raspbian, 3g

When I am using raspbian with a 4g USB modem, sometimes the network goes down and there is no option to bring back the network unless I reboot the raspbian.

In such cases, I try:

```
service networking restart
```

with a cron every hour; this doesn't work.

I tried also `ifdown -a && ifup -a` -- not much better.

The thing is, when I execute these commands in a terminal, I get no output.

What is the solution to bring network as if I rebooted?

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.100  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::48f5:e07c:1544:2d24  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b8:27:eb:38:6e:29  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 23902  bytes 8949877 (8.5 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 17  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 30039  bytes 6388288 (6.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 20996  bytes 8495857 (8.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 20996  bytes 8495857 (8.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:6d:3b:7c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: how exactly do you connect initially? Did you set up a configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` or did you have to do more than that to connect in the first place?

Comment: no config at all

i have to do  plug usb modem and it works like ethernet wire

Comment: Could you post the outputs of `ifconfig -a`? In the case in which everything is handled by the usb device, [power cycling the usb device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4702316/2519977) might help, altough it might not be the best of solutions.

Comment: post edited with ifconfig

Comment: Did you do this while the modem was plugged in? Because it's not showing up. If it's showing up in the future I'd recommend editing out the ip address for security reasons. Right now, you seem to be connected to your local ethernet only.

Comment: its plugged and internet working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87127/discussion-between-rudib-and-user1335838).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I found to work on Raspbian is:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down && sleep 5 && sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Comment: You'd be marginally better ignoring the result of bringing the network down, so that if there's an error the network still comes back up: `sudo sh -c 'ifconfig wlan0 down; sleep 5; ifconfig wlan0 up'`